# Serving content depending on http accept header - caching problems?

Tags: ajax, http, google-chrome

I'm developing an application which is supposed to serve different content for "normal" browser requests and AJAX requests for the same URL requested. 
(in fact, encapsulate the response HTML in JSON object if the request is AJAX).

For this purpose, I'm detecting an AJAX request on the server side, and processing the response appropriately, see the pseudocode below:

```
function process_response(request, response)
{
 if request.is_ajax 
 {
   response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
   response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
   response.content = JSON( some_data... )
 }
}
```

The problem is that when the first AJAX request to the currently viewed URL is made **strange things happens on Google Chrome** - if, right after the response comes and is processed via JavaScript, user clicks some link (static, which redirects to other page) and then clicks back button in the browser, he sees the **returned JSON** code instead of the rendered website (logging the server I can say that **no request** is made). It seems for me that Chrome stores the latest request response for the specific URL, and doesn't take into account that it has different content-type etc.

Is that a bug in the Chrome or **am I misusing HTTP protocol** ?

--- update 12 11 2012, 12:38 UTC

following PatrikAkerstrand answer, I've found following Chrome bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=94369

any ideas how to **avoid this behaviour**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also include a [`Vary-header`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.44):

```
response.headers['Vary'] = 'Content-Type'
```

Comment: Well, it didn't fixed the problem. However, following your response I've found it is a google chrome bug. Now, any ideas how to avoid this behaviour? * http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=94369

Comment: Vary lists the *request* fields thre response varies on.

Answer (score 0):

`Vary` is a standard way to control caching context in content negotiation. Unfortunately it has also buggy implementations in some browsers, see [Browser cache vary broken](http://jakearchibald.com/2014/browser-cache-vary-broken/).

I would suggest using unique URLs. 
Depending of you framework capabilities you can redirect (302) the browser to URL + `.html` to force response format and make cache key unique within browser session. Then for AJAX requests you can still keep suffix-less URL. Alternatively you may suffix AJAX URL with `.json` instead .

Another options are: prefixing AJAX requests with `/api` or adding some cache boosting query params `?rand=1234`.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `cache-control` to `no-store` made it in my case, while `no-cache` didn't. This may have unwanted side effects though.

> `no-store`: The response may not be stored in any cache. Although other directives may be set, this alone is the only directive you need in preventing cached responses on modern browsers.
>
> Source: [Mozilla Developer Network - HTTP Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control)